# Problem in installing pip in Ubuntu 16.04⠀

Tags: pip

Problem in installing pip in Ubuntu 16.04 . It installed correctly I guess, but when I checked through `pip -V` then it shows this error:

```
anshul@ANSHUL:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/144 kB of archives.
After this operation, 635 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
(Reading database ... 282702 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
anshul@ANSHUL:~$ pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Comment: I have done the same steps but still, I m getting same error when i'm checking pip -V

Comment: As a matter of interest, why are you still using 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try Purging and Installing pip again. i can see that the files where not downloaded from repository it is installing using the cache from the temp which is already downloaded. i am suggesting to make a clean install that might help.
first purge pip and do a autoclean and autoremove on the apt and then try installing again.

Comment: I have tried this but getting same error:

anshul@ANSHUL:~$ pip -V

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>

    from pip import main

ImportError: cannot import name main

anshul@ANSHUL:~$ which pip

/usr/bin/pip

Comment: Then try reinstalling Python or try pip for Python 3

Comment: PIP issues https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get update
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```